# MVC4 authentication & authorization for custom database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

first of all I wanna say that I know there are many topics about this and I'm also searching the web to understand the whole concept that mvc deals with the security and keeping user information etc, but I wanted to get some advises, ideas from pros while I'm reading about this, so I'm gonna explain my situation and I'm thankful for the helps.

lets say I have a custom table called "Users"

```
public class Users : KySerializableObject
{    
    [required]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    [required]
    public virtual string userName {get; set; }

    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("UserType")]
    public virtual int UserTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

now what I know is that mvc provides a simpleMembership which works for a simple situations, but since I'm having different types of users and additional information for my User, what I'm wondering is how can I take a use of [authorize] tag for my user with different roles which I prefer to use my own roles table and also how can I deal with the login process ? I mean the part that I should use FormsAuthentication, or I'm not even sure I should use that or not, I'm really lost and I'd love to hear some advises from you guys. I'm not asking for codes or anything, any link to a good guidance that explains my situation would be awesome.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

i have same situation and i am following a procedure for 
Authentication FORMS Authentication
Authorization  i write my own wrapper class to RoleProvider. with this you can directly use like

[Authorize (Rules = "Admin,Users")]

if your problem is authentication/authorization it will helps you perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

[Please take a look at this forum discussion in the ASP.Net forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1891458.aspx/1?MVC%203%200%20Authentication%20and%20Authorization)

If you know your way around authentication, you should have nailed the code in here. But, for your requirement, please take a close look at this bit of code

```
string[] roles = //you add your custom roles for the current user to this string list
GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name),
```

roles);//then you create a Generic principle

```
Context.User = userPrinciple;
```

remember, if you are putting this code outside of Global.asax file, then `Context` is the `HttpContext.Current`

Now you can use `[Authorize(Roles = "yourRole1, yourRole2")]`

Hope that helps.